# Is hyperparameter tuning with different samples of data on each run a bad idea?

Tags: hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter

I have 2k time series and want to optimize the hyperparameters of my prophet model. It takes 1 hour to train and evaluate on every time series for each hyperparam combination. So, I want to run it on a sample to speed thing up.

Options:

1. Use the same sample of training data for every hyperparameter combination (I've been doing this but feel like I'm not getting my money's worth)
2. Use a different sample of training data for each hyperparam combination (Gives me more data coverage but throws another variable in the mix - how can I be sure that this set of params does perform better and not that it just got lucky with the data?)
3. Manually craft a smaller dataset that contains a good combo of time series to test the model.

I feel like 3 is the right answer... but how bad is number 2? Would you ever advise this?

Note: [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44109/disadvantages-of-hyperparameter-tuning-on-a-random-sample-of-dataset) question asks about the disadvantages of number 1. I'm asking about number 2.

Answer (score 2):

In essence, it is said that "there is no data as more data". So the training process should be done on as much data as you have, this also involves hyper-parameter tuning.

Now one thing you can do to reduce the size of the data, is to drop duplicate or 'similar' rows of data. You have to define the criteria for 'similarity' your self, check for distant metrics as a start. This point goes in the direction of manually crafting your dataset.

Second, try to drop correlated columns (you can use simple Pearson correlation for that and take any cut-off threshold that suits you). This is btw the most effective method.

There is a huge set of analytical tool-box available for timeseries such as ARIMA, GARCH, ARCH, etc. There you will also find methods on comparing time series as well. I would suggest to have look in there to help filter out unwanted/redundant timeseries. By unwanted I mean that there might be some timeseries simple enough to be represented by MA or AR processes so no need to fit the entire prophet model on them.

There is also a nice blog on predicting stock prices using FBprophet on empirischtech.at website, have a look in there for more insights. Plus, DeepAR from SageMaker is already capable to processing multiple timeseries data but I believe it can only be used with AWS account.